# Infopath form in SP 2013 with links to attachments

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I need to develop a Info path form in SP 2013 where I need to show the attachments as a link.
[this](http://tihomirignatov.blogspot.in/2009/09/attach-files-to-infopath-form.html) URL describes how to achieve this in info path 2007 but I am not able to figure out how to achieve the same in 2013.

The second part is when the user clicks on the attachment link (lets say an excel file) It should be open in MS-excel for the user to edit. Once the user click save in ms-excel the changes should reflect in the attachment file as well.

Comment: The steps should mostly be the same between InfoPath versions for that approach.  What have you tried so far?  As to the second part, that's not quite how attachments work. You would need to remove then update the attachment, pretty sure. You may be better off with a link to a file in a document library if this is what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three workarounds for the issue.

#### 1.Use the default form in the list.

1.1 When you add the attachment firstly, it will display the URL of the attachment like the picture below. But you cannot click the URL to open the file.
 [image]

1.2 After that, when you edit the item, you can click the file name and it will open the file in the office application directly.
 [image]

#### 2. Use InfoPath form.

2.1 You could customize the form in the InfoPath form. Add the rich text box and set the value as the attachment field.

[image]
2.2 After that, when you add attachment, it will not display the URL of the attachment in the first time, when you edit the item, it will display the URL of the attachment. If you have multiple attachments, it will display in one line, you should break the line.
 [image]
2.3 If you want to edit the file, you could click the aa.docx and click “open”. It will open the file in the office application.
 [image]

#### 3. Use library.

You could consider using library to store and edit the documents.

Comment: Thanks Amy have already done it using the second approach